# Can you assign existing value to the array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

Is it possible to assign an existing variable to the array? Let's say if we have 5 variables `a, b, c, d, e` and we want to assign them to an array `n[5]`, but I can't assign the names of variables in the array, so what do I do then?

Comment: You could do something like `n[0] = a` etc. Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Could you give an example of the code that does not work (complete with declarations and the error message from the compiler)? It might show where you are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do it like this:

```
T n[5] = {a, b, c, d, e};
```

assuming the variables are all of type `T`.

Comment: And if they're not `int`, you can cast them.

Comment: @Barmar Actually, I didn't mean specifically `int`. Edited.

Comment: Whatever the type, you can potentially convert them.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's true.